# Momentum-space Feynman rules (Matthew D. Schwartz, Quantum field Theory and the Standard Model)

Tags: quantum-field-theory, fourier-transform, correlation-functions, s-matrix-theory

I'm reading the Matthew D. Schwartz, Quantum field Theory and the Standard Model, section 7.3 Momentum-space Feynman rules.

I think that I'm beginner in quantum field theory and so please understand for some seemingly elementary question.

Anyway, let's veiw the next image;

[image]

[image]

I'm trying to understand the underlined statements.

Q. 1) Why can we express $<f|S|i>$ as such a form (7.82) by the LSZ formula? What are $\phi(x_1)$ and $\phi(x_2)$?

Q. 2) Why can we express $<f|S|i>$ approximately as (7.83)?

Q. 3) Finally why the equation (7.84) true? Why the $x_1$ integral gives $(2\pi)^{4}\delta^{4}(p_1 - p_i)$ and the $x_2$ integral gives $(2\pi)^{4}\delta^{4}(p_2 - p_f)$? Where did $p_1$ and $ p_2$ in the dirac delta functions come from?

Comment: Regarding question 1 the answer lies in the LSZ reduction formula itself. Look at equation 6.1 in Schwartz'. You see all the operators $(\Box_i+m^2)$ acting on the Green's function? Well, integrate by parts and transfer those operators to act on the external wavefunctions $e^{\pm i p_ix_i}$.  In the massless case, you will just get the momentum factors you see in 7.82

Comment: This post (v4) seems _too broad._ Consider to only ask 1 question per post.

Comment: Uhm.. Yes, O.K.